# write the binary string into an image file

Tags: javascript, node.js

in php we can write the binary string into an image file by using this

```
$binary = hex2bin($hex);
file_put_contents("myphoto.png", $binary);
```

it uses the file_put_contents in order to  Write it to disk:

in  node.js how can we achieve this like the file_put_contents. ?

**EDIT:**
I tried this as suggested by the comments but it gives me an error

```
 var binarydata = fs.readFileSync('mybin.txt',{flag:'w'});

        fs.writeFileSync( 'myphoto.png', binarydata );


Error: EPERM, operation not permitted
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:552:19)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:389:28)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Reading the [documentation for the `fs` (file system) module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system) would be a good place to start.

Comment: something like `fs.writeFileSync()` and making sure what you are writing is a `Buffer` type

Comment: @Catalyst, can you show me some snippet please

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you:

```
var fs = require( 'fs' );
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream( 'myphoto.jpg' );
wstream.write( $binary );
wstream.end();
```

Here is the documentation for node.js fs-module: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

If you want to do something when it has finished use

```
fs.writeFileSync( 'myphoto.png', $binary );
```

or do it asynchronous:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('myphoto.jpg');
wstream.on( 'finish', function() {
    // do something
});
wstream.write( $binary );
wstream.end();
```

Read file and write to another file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile( 'temp.txt', function( err, data ) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var wstream = fs.createWriteStream( 'myphoto.jpg' );
    wstream.on( 'finish', function() {
        // do something
    });
    wstream.write( data );
    wstream.end();
});
```

**Edit:** My code was working all time, it just has to be 'myphoto.jpg' instead of 'myphoto.png' ;)
So the solution isn't to do it like this, you just have to rename the file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.renameSync( 'temp.txt', 'myphoto.jpg' );
```

or if you need your temp.txt, then copy it like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.createReadStream( 'temp.txt' ).pipe( fs.createWriteStream( 'myphoto.jpg' ) );
```

Comment: my binary data is stored in a file temp.txt,how can I get it first ?

Comment: Please read the documentation... fs.readFileSync( 'temp.txt' ); I'll also edit my post to add an asynchronous codesnippet to my post, then you should know all you need

Comment: Error: EPERM, operation not permitted

Comment: Do you use Linux? Then start node with sudo

Comment: im in windows...I tried your code. but the image cannot be open

Comment: try console.log( data ), is this your temp.txt?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76920/discussion-between-joriktos-and-jemz).